# Frontend checking if token(jwt) has expired

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jwt

In my react-redux app, I want to show a modal login form whenever the token has expired.

My solutions were:

1. Save the `expires_in` value in redux and have it countdown until it reaches **0**, and then show the modal login form.
2. Implement **polling**, wherein I have to send an API request using the current token, every nth minutes, and have it validate the token.

But my conclusion were (Not tested, but most likely will happen):

1. For solution #1, I think the token validity duration that I set in the front-end is not in sync with the server-side's duration. Thus, there will be an instance where a user sends a request, though not prompted with the modal login form, the request will be unauthenticated.
2. For solution #2, I think it will have a performance drawback to constantly have a request every nth time, considering the mass of users that are currently logged in.

My question is that, what is the right way to check if the token has expired? I've searched for some laravel-reactjs hooks but I cannot find any.

Comment: Why not redirect the user back to a login page instead of merely showing a popup like in 1.?

Comment: Bruh, that's a business preference. I don't think that's the issue here. The question is the validation.